# ngOnInit called everytime i change route

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a controller implements OnInit 
The problem here is whenever i change the route and come back to same component ngOnInit is called everytime. What i am doing wrong i am not able to understand.Anybody please help me.

```
@Component({
    selector:'test-list',
    templateUrl:'./testlist.component.html',
    styles:[`.testname{
        text-transform : capitalize;
    }`]
})
export class TestListComponent implements OnInit{
    testList:Array<Test>;
    constructor(private testService:TestService,private router:Router){}
    ngOnInit(){
        this.testService.getTest()
        .subscribe(
            data=>this.testList = <Array<Test>>data,
            error=>alert(error)
        );
        console.log("ngInit")
    }
    editTest = (id)=>{
        this.router.navigate(['createtest',id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but that's the expected behavior? You change the route, and you return back the component is a new instance of `TestListComponent` so `OnInit()` call is expected.

Comment: It should be called only once as i know when the TestListComponent is created not every time when i come back to same component. Am i right?

Comment: It's the purpose of OnInit. Every time the component is created, ngOnInit is called !

Comment: is component is created every time when we change the route?

Comment: No, why would it? It's a new instance every time component is created. It's not a static class where it get's created once.

Comment: that's what i am asking why ngOnInit is called every time when route is changed

Comment: I think we answered it pretty well... `It's a new instance every time component is called`

Comment: I think Vikram you are getting confused here. @12seconds last reply was for `It should be called only once as i know when the TestListComponent is created not every time when i come back to same component. Am i right?` and not `component is created every time when we change the route?`.

Comment: This means component is recreated every time route is changed. Is there any way to control this? So that component is created only once.

Comment: Any reason why you would want that though? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: 1In testService.getTest(), have you mapped an Response to a json payload `as Array<Test>`? <Array<Test>>data .... is the outer <> necessary? if your return type is as I suggested this.testList = data would suffice

Comment: I don't know if this helps Vikram, but think of it this way...: Let's say your component gets called twice from parent component with different data/id's, you'd need two instances for each set of data. If id 1 had 2 children, id2 had 3 children, the rendering would be different. A component can be a container for others too..

Answer (score 2):

`ngOnInit()` is executed everytime the component is loaded. It doesn't need to be called. This is a lifecycle hook for doing initial stuff. You can learn more about angular lifecycle hooks 
[here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

If in the constructor you subscribe to the active route, ngInit will be called every time the router navigates to that page.

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(async (params) => {
        if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            // TODO save the params
        }
    });
}

ngOnInit(){
    console.log('ngOnInit called');
}
```