# Why ngOnInit is getting called every time repeatedly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Per Angular ( https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit that says *ngOnInit is called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated*. ),

So ngOnInit should be called once, but as shown in the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bFTOZfeiD8rhYlp3l2TS?p=preview) ( that is a copy from https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5 ) , I only modified 
*app/heroes/heroes.component.ts* and 
*app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts* to have console.log

and when F12 (Developer Tools) is opened, the console shows the log repeatedly when route is changed.

I looked 
[why ngOnInit called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787795/why-ngoninit-called-twice) ,
[Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit) , 
[Angular 2 App Component ngOnInit called twice when using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783511/angular-2-app-component-ngoninit-called-twice-when-using-iframe) , 
[ngOnInit called everytime i change route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239799/ngoninit-called-everytime-i-change-route)

but could not understand why ngOnInit is being called everytime.

```
console.log("ngOnInit in All Heroes");
console.log("ngOnInit InDashBoard");
```

Answer (score 5):

When the route changes the component is *destroyed*, then when the route changes back the component is *initialised* again.

Add this to `DashboardComponent` to see for yourself:

```js
    ngOnDestroy() {
      console.log("ngOnDestroy InDashBoard");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the Problem in my case was the way I was bootstrapping the Child Components.
 In my `@NgModule` decorator’s metadata object ,I was passing `child component` in the bootstrap property along with `parent component`.
Passing the child components in bootstrap property was resetting my child components properties and making `OnInit()` fired twice.

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ], // to use two-way data binding ‘FormsModule’
declarations: [ parentComponent,Child1,Child2], //all components
 //bootstrap: [parentComponent,Child1,Child2] // will lead to errors in binding Inputs in Child components
 bootstrap: [parentComponent] //use parent components only
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe you want OnInit to fire twice.   You need to be able to determine the initial instantiation of the component separate from sequential instantiations.   So if I want something to be executed the first time and only the first time I put it in the constructor.   If the component is not Lazy loaded the constructor will only get called on the initial instantiation.  But if I want to call something every time the route returns to the component it goes in the onInit.

Comment: The constructor should not be charged